# python filtering scatterplot base off dates

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a csv file where the contents look like:

```
        Datetime       Count Diff
0   2012-08-25 00:00:00 8   0.0
1   2012-08-25 01:00:00 2   1.0
2   2012-08-25 02:00:00 6   2.0
3   2012-08-25 03:00:00 2   3.0
```

I currently have a scatterplot that plots all the data (x-axis represents the hours elapsed since August 25th, 2012 and the y-axis represents the number of tickets sold over each hour)

I am trying to filter the scatterplot so that it just takes in the first month. How would I do this? Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('2.csv')
df["Datetime"] =pd.to_datetime(df["Datetime"])
df.head()

df["Diff"] = (df["Datetime"]  - df["Datetime"][0]) / np.timedelta64(1,'h')
df.fillna(0, inplace =True)
df

plt.scatter(df["Diff"], df["Count"], marker='.' )
```

Comment: Sort by date; groupby date; plot the first group.?

Comment: how would you do that ?

Comment: Excellant docs  - make sure the date column data are datetime types. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html